# Onclick button does not call js function in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, onclick

I have a button that must call my js function, but nothing happens when i do (there is no get requests)

My HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="checker" id="button{{answer.id}}" onclick="mark_as_correct({{answer.id}});">
</button>
```

My JS function:

```
function mark_as_correct(qid) {
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'url answerajaxcorrect',
        type: 'post',
        data: {id: qid},
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById('correct' + qid).innerHTML = "Correct!"
            var button = document.getElementById('button' + qid)
            button.parentNode.removeChild(button)
        },
        failure: function(data) {
            alert('error')
        }
    })
}
```

I do include my js to template:

```
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
```

And there is how my view looks like:

```
@login_required
def correct_ajax(request):
    qid = int(request.POST.get("id"))
    answer = get_object_or_404(Answer, id=qid)
    if answer.author == request.user:
        answer.is_correct = True
        answer.save()

        return JsonResponse({
            "is_correct": True,
        })
    else:
        return JsonResponse({
            "is_correct": False,
        })
```

I am new to js and django, so it is hard for me to understand the source of my problem, please help.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="mark_as_correct({{answer.id}});"`

The function *reference* you pass to `onclick` needs to be able to take an `event` parameter.  When you point to a function with assigned argument to `onclick`, the browser will execute the function at read time, and assign the *result* of that function to `onclick`.

In your case, you can just create an anonymous function to do the trick:

```
<button type="button" id="checker" id="button{{answer.id}}" onclick="function() { mark_as_correct({{answer.id}}) };">
```

Comment: If i understood correctly, my function will be called, but not by click, but that does not happen. I tried to use your code,  at first glance, nothing has changed